# Using enums to index a bit array

Tags: c#, enumeration

The application is a windows-based C# user interface for an embedded control and monitoring system.

The embedded system (written in C) maintains a table of faults which it sends to the c# application. The fault table contains one bit for each fault, stored in structure. Now from the point of view of the user interface the table is somewhat sparse - There are only a few of the fault bits that we are interested in, so the structure can be represented as below:

```
 typedef struct
 {
    BYTE FaultsIAmNotInterestedIn0[14];
    BYTE PowerSupplyFaults[4];
    BYTE FaultsIAmNotInterestedIn1[5];
    BYTE MachineryFaults[2];
    BYTE FaultsIAmNotInterestedIn2[5];
    BYTE CommunicationFaults[4];
 }FAULT_TABLE;
```

Now, I want to be able to index each fault bit that I am interested in. In C I would use an enumeration to do this:

```
typedef enum
{
  FF_PSU1 = offsetof(FAULT_TABLE,PowerSupplyFaults)*8,
  FF_PSU2,
  FF_PSU3, 
  FF_PSU4,
  FF_PSU5,
  FF_PSU6,
  FF_PSU7,
  FF_PSU8,
  FF_PSU9,
  FF_PSU10,
  FF_PSU11,
  FF_PSU12,
  FF_PSU13,

  FF_MACHINERY1 = offsetof(FAULT_TABLE,MachineryFaults)*8,
  FF_MACHINERY2,
  FF_MACHINERY3,
  FF_MACHINERY4,
  FF_MACHINERY5,
  FF_MACHINERY6,
  FF_MACHINERY7,
  FF_MACHINERY8,
  FF_MACHINERY9,
  FF_MACHINERY10,

  FF_COMMS1 = offsetof(FAULT_TABLE,CommunicationFaults)*8,
  FF_COMMS2,
  FF_COMMS3,
  FF_COMMS4,
  FF_COMMS5,
  FF_COMMS6,
  FF_COMMS7,
  FF_COMMS8,
  FF_COMMS9,
  FF_COMMS10,
  FF_COMMS11,
  FF_COMMS12,
  FF_COMMS13
}FAULT_FLAGS;
```

Is there a way that I can create a similar enumeration, based on a data structure in C#?

Comment: Which version of the .net framework will you be using?

Answer (score 0):

Add a Flags attribute to your enum. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.FLAGSATTRIBUTE);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true

Answer (score 0):

You can get the offset of an element of a struct with `Marshal.OffsetOf`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.offsetof.aspx

Your struct can be created in pretty much the same way although you need to ensure you specify the layout (although I suppose this depends on how the struct is instantiated).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute(v=vs.71).aspx

However... the problem will come with the Enum.  Enum values need to be compile time constants and Marshal.OffsetOf isn't.  So you may have to store the offsets as static members of a class instead.

I also think you'll probably have to stray into unsafe code to make any real use of these offsets once you have them - and there is probably a better way to approach whatever you want to do in managed code.

Comment: Thanks James - I guess I will have to look for another method

Comment: What is the objective here?  You are receiving the struct from non-managed code (via p/invoke?) - so provided the struct has appropriate layout attributes everything in it will be accessible via the appropriately aligned members.  If you want to access it dynamically (in some sense) you can use reflection instead of messing about with memory offsets for example.  Better still make it a class and add members to access the required properties.  Making the internal representation of the data irrelevant.

Comment: The objective is simplicity. (Oops - pressed return prematurely - more to come)

Comment: The objective is simplicity. The lower level comms protocols pass the received fault table as a simple byte array to the fault display class. By having enums as described I could simply treat this as a bit array of fault flags. If the compiler could generate the bit indices from the structure (as it can in C/C++) I am avoiding manual calculations and potential error and making the code more robust for any future change in the structure of the fault table.

Comment: But I do realise they are other ways of doing it, but this is a method that is used frequently across our c and c++ code base and I wondered if there was a direct translation into C#. As you probably can gather I am pretty naive in c#. Is there a good reason why the offset of a field in a structure cannot be determined at compile time?

Comment: Obviously the compiler can determine the offsets at compile time,  but the compiler isn't clever enough to evaluate the OffsetOf method at compile time (or even know it is a compile time constant).  Since these are constants you could just hardcode the offsets.  But generally I think trying to apply lower level C/C++ tricks to C# isn't going to work or is going to be ugly.  From a C# perspective you're making the code less robust as you're exposing the implementation outside of the class - but I suppose it depends on what school of programming you're coming from.

Comment: However - you can avoid hard coding the offsets because you can call Marshal.OffsetOf at runtime,  you'd just be storing the values in (hopefully private) static variables rather than constants.  There is practically no difference.

Comment: There is just no compile time equivalent of this in C#.  Besides the fact it doesn't really fit the language I suppose it's also the case that the C# compiler/JITer doesn't guarantee any particular layout and the JITer is free to do it differently in different environments if it wants to.  You will use layout attributes to fix the layout - but this is a special case.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an enum to map the bits/flags, but you cannot map more than 32 bits.

In your example, I would create several const of long (64 bits). That won't solve the bit limitation when your array is very long (e.g. the first one).

Another trick is creating a static function that gives you the value of the bit (as a bool), upon the bit position in the array. In this case, the position (being a constant) is surely within the int range.

```
public static bool GetBit(byte[] buffer, int pos)
{
  return (buffer[pos >> 3] & (1 << (pos & 7)) != 0);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create an enum that specifies the bit-offset within each set of bytes:

```
enum PowerSupplyFaults
{
    PowerSupplyFault1, PowerSupplyFault2, PowerSupplyFault3
}
```

`PowerSupplyFault1` will be auto-assigned 0, Fault2 as 1, etc.

Assuming you receive a struct that mirrors the C version:

```
struct FaultTable
{
    // ...

    public byte[] PowerSupplyFaults;
    public byte[] MachineFaults;

    // ...
}
```

You can test for a fault by feeding the bytes into a [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) and testing by index:

```
FaultTable faults = GetFaultTable();
BitArray psu_faults = new BitArray( fault_table.PowerSupplyFaults );

if ( psu_faults[ (int)PowerSupplyFaults.PowerSupplyFault3 ] )
{
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can walk all the bits and see which are set:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < psu_faults.Length; i++ )
{
    if ( psu_faults[ i ] )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "PSU fault: {0}", (PowerSupplyFaults)i );
    }
}
```